# Does PDO ever close persistent connections?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, pdo

I switched to using PDO persistent connections. I encountered situations where MySQL (correctly) closes a connection on its end (due to inactivity) and PDO doesn't pick up on it, keeps the connection available in its cache, and from that point on - any attempt to use this connection results in a failure.

From what I've read this behavior is "by design" (to me it looks like PDO is going out of its way to not support persistent connections).

Either way, I would like to know if PDO would *ever* close a connection in its pool. I get it that it doesn't check the connection's state, but is there any kind of timer or periodic cleanup, configurable or hard-coded?

Comment: You have to ping the connection manually in PHP from time to time if you wish to maintain working connection to your database. The time MySQL closes the inactive connection can be changed in the MySQL configuration

Comment: what about certain error message you get?

Comment: @YourCommonSense The error I get when trying to use a connection that had been closed is something like "MySQL server had gone away".

Comment: @mike so the answer is that PDO never closes a connection?

Comment: No, it's a persistent connection like the name says

Comment: @mike closing persistent connections a long while after they had been created (e.g. after 8 hours) would not contradict with their name and would be a sensible thing to do, if PDO is unable to actually detect when MySQL closes the connection.

Comment: Whatever mate...

Answer (score 1):

One should not worry about the persistence of a connection.

If you are building a web page -- it should finish long before the connection times out.

If you have a long-running application that is not touching the database for huge time spans, then think about rearranging the code or closing and re-opening or discovering that it was closed and re-opening.

Note that a connection can close for any of a lot of reasons -- many related to hiccups in the network.  Therefore, your application should be ready to recover from a closed connection, regardless of how "persistent" it claims to be.

"Connection pooling" is handled at many levels -- in the client library, in the "proxy server", even in the MySQL server.  They all act differently.

Connection pooling is not all that useful.  Virtually every performance problem I have chased down did *not* have to do with the time it takes to [re]establish a connection.

Other RDBMS vendors have had horribly slow Connect times, leading the industry to invent connection pooling and persistent connections.  But MySQL has little need for such.

There are several timeouts that can trigger closing a connection; you are at the mercy of the DBA / SE / Cloud provider as to what values they are set to.

PDO is just one of many layers, so your question is too narrow.  I hope I have provided a broader answer.

Comment: I appreciate the effort and details but it doesn't actually answer my question (which, narrow as it was, was about specific PDO behavior (or lack-of)). A couple of notes: with SSL enabled, MySQL connections take much longer. While I'd agree that every (or almost every) performance issue can be solved by modifying the design or coding practices, I argue that there are valid business situations where switching to PDO persistent connections gives the needed edge and is preferable to modifying the architecture.

Comment: Regarding handling errors gracefully: there's a difference between handling a random event (in which it may be OK to just return some error message to the user and even preferable over re-connecting due to various reasons), and between inevitably routinely having these errors (just because the underlying library doesn't periodically resets connections).